# What's the best way to add a button in an AccordionHeader that should not toggle the Accordion?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, accordion, react-bootstrap

We use React Bootstraps Accordions (version 2.7.0) and I would like to add a button in the accordion header, which should do something different than toggle the Accordion.

```js
const doSomethingElse = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
}

<AccordionItem eventKey={eventKey} className={classes}>
   <AccordionHeader>My fancy headline <Button onClick={doSomethingElse}>Click me</Button></AccordionHeader>
   <AccordionBody>{children}</AccordionBody>
</AccordionItem>
```

My `doSomethingElse` method is never reached if I add a breakpoint or console log there. My button also has a tooltip that is not triggered - it seems like the AccordionHeader does not pass down click events.

We've covered this on other non-react pages with a jQuery onMouseEnter handler on the buttons in accordions which sets the surrounding Accordion to uncollapse and resets it again to being collapse on mouseenter, but that is quite ugly and feels hacky.

What's the proper way to achieve such a behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Accordion.Header is itself a button component so you won't be able to achieve directly. Instead you can try creating a custom component for the AccordionHeader.

```
import Accordion from "react-bootstrap/Accordion";
import { useAccordionButton } from "react-bootstrap/AccordionButton";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";

function CustomToggle({ children, eventKey }) {
  const decoratedOnClick = useAccordionButton(eventKey, () =>
    console.log("totally custom!"),
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={decoratedOnClick}>{children}</div>
      <button type="button" style={{ backgroundColor: "pink" }}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Example() {
  return (
    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
      <Card>
        <Card.Header>
          <CustomToggle eventKey="0">My custom header</CustomToggle>
        </Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
          <Card.Body>Hello! I'm the body</Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    </Accordion>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

Read more about it here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/components/accordion#custom-toggle